# Property of orthogonal and skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ be a $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix and $X$ be a matrix such that

$X=(A+I)^{-1}(A-I)$

then show that $X$ is a skew-symmetric matrix,whenever $n$ is an odd integer.

Comment: $A+I$ may not be invertible.

Comment: $A+I$ may even be the zero matrix ;)

Comment: You need to assume explicitly that $A+I$ is invertible (or that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$).

Comment: OK.It was not specified but then it should be given.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is orthogonal such that $\color{blue}{\text{$A+I$ is invertible}}$, then
$$
X+X^T=(A+I)^{-1}(A-I)+(A-I)^T(A+I)^{-T}
=(A+I)^{-1}[\underbrace{(A-I)(A+I)^T+(A+I)(A-I)^T}_{=0}](A+I)^{-T}=0.
$$